# Get Post ID with insert/edit link

Tags: save-post, wp-editor, id

Hi I want to get the post ID from the post selected in the insert/edit link button.

I would normally do:

```
<a 
    data-id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" 
    href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
    Sample page link
</a>
```

[image]

But whenever the user adds the links from the tinymce content editor all they get is the permalink, I don't know how to hook in. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

*Edit* I would like to avoid a plugin. But this is what I am after.. ideally without the bloated [shortcode]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to your question (hooking into the insert/edit link functionality), but possibly an alternate method that can achieve the same goal (inputting a permalink, outputting a Post ID):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid